# Building A Backbone.js User Model, Collection and View For A RESTful JSON API

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, restful-architecture

So I just finished making a fully RESTful JSON API for a User in node. When you visit `http://localhost:8080/user/create` you get what you would normally expect- a new User which is then stored in a database, in my case mongoDB.

```
{
  "createdAt": Date(),
  "updatedAt": Date(),
  "id": 1
}
```

My experience lies in server-side programming but I'm trying to get into Backbone.js. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how to create a very simple Backbone User Model and View for registering a User?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Backbone has a REST API, you only need 1 URL to do all the REST actions (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, [PATCH]). So if you need more than POST request, you may want to consider changing user/create to user only as it wouldn't make sense for the other type of requests.

Now for the code, based on this form:

```
<div id="form">
  <input type="text" id="username" />
  <button id="post">Send</button>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tJ3Yu/) is the full example I made to create a user with an input. Pretty simple, ask for more precisions if you need.